# The mesh stretches when the bone is rotated

Tags: mesh, rigging, retopology

An example of stretching mesh:

[image: screen1]

Example of stretching a mesh close-up:

[image: screen2]

`Automatic weight` has smoothed the situation a bit, but it still stretch, here is an example:

[image: screen3]

The same example, but only in close-up:

[image: screen4]

Here is the blend file [image]

Comment: Giving the topology, I'm not sure you can fix this, actually it's better to have a mesh with a T pose

Comment: I agree with @moonboots. Parts of the mesh under the arms are too close together to be able to weight paint successfully.